# Fill group of data with its unique reference with pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have invoice data as below

```
+----------------+-----------+-------------+-----+-------+
|       ID       |   Date    | Description | QTY | Price |
+----------------+-----------+-------------+-----+-------+
| 1XpP1          | 08-Feb-19 | A           |   1 |     8 |
| Total [INV001] |           |             |   8 |     8 |
| 1XpQ1          | 08-Feb-19 | A           |   1 |    10 |
| 1XpQ1          | 08-Feb-19 | B           |   1 |    10 |
| Total [INV002] |           |             |   2 |    20 |
| 1XpP1          | 08-Feb-19 | A           |   1 |    12 |
| 1XpP1          | 08-Feb-19 | B           |   1 |    12 |
| 1XpP1          | 08-Feb-19 | C           |   1 |    12 |
| 1XpP1          | 08-Feb-19 | D           |   1 |    12 |
| Total [INV003] |           |             |   4 |    48 |
+----------------+-----------+-------------+-----+-------+
```

Notice the `Total` row under each invoice. which contains the `invoice No`. I want to delete this row entirely & add the `Total` reference in a difference column separately. My desired output is as below.

```
+-------+-----------+-------------+-----+-------+----------------+
|  ID   |   Date    | Description | QTY | Price |  ID Adjusted   |
+-------+-----------+-------------+-----+-------+----------------+
| 1XpP1 | 08-Feb-19 | A           |   1 |     8 | Total [INV001] |
| 1XpQ1 | 08-Feb-19 | A           |   1 |    10 | Total [INV002] |
| 1XpQ1 | 08-Feb-19 | B           |   1 |    10 | Total [INV002] |
| 1XpP1 | 08-Feb-19 | A           |   1 |    12 | Total [INV003] |
| 1XpP1 | 08-Feb-19 | B           |   1 |    12 | Total [INV003] |
| 1XpP1 | 08-Feb-19 | C           |   1 |    12 | Total [INV003] |
| 1XpP1 | 08-Feb-19 | D           |   1 |    12 | Total [INV003] |
+-------+-----------+-------------+-----+-------+----------------+
```

please give me a kick start to solve this issue. I've no idea how to group this data. as the number of lines in the invoice varies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with [`Series.str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) for missing values for non matched rows and back filling them and then filter by inverted mask with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), last is possible add [`DataFrame.copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) for avoid `SettingwithCopyWarning` if is processing data later:

```
m = df['ID'].str.endswith(']')
df['ID Adjusted'] = df['ID'].where(m).bfill()
df = df[~m].copy()
print (df)
      ID       Date Description  QTY  Price     ID Adjusted
0  1XpP1  08-Feb-19           A    1      8  Total [INV001]
2  1XpQ1  08-Feb-19           A    1     10  Total [INV002]
3  1XpQ1  08-Feb-19           B    1     10  Total [INV002]
5  1XpR1  08-Feb-19           A    1     12  Total [INV003]
6  1XpR1  08-Feb-19           B    1     12  Total [INV003]
7  1XpR1  08-Feb-19           C    1     12  Total [INV003]
8  1XpR1  08-Feb-19           D    1     12  Total [INV003]
```

Comment: first time I encountered `bfill()` method. let me dig deeper. thank you